# How to wait for a list of async function calls in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, concurrency

I have a list of `async` functions that I want to execute concurrently and then wait for all them to finish. The working code I have right now is:

```
async fn start_consumers(&self) {
    for consumer in &self.consumers {
        consumer.consume().await;
    }
}
```

This is not quite accurate as the functions are executed serially. I am looking for something like [`join!`](https://docs.rs/async-std/0.99.12/async_std/future/macro.join.html), but which works on a dynamic vector. With that I should be able to write something like:

```
async fn start_consumers(&self) {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    for consumer in &self.consumers {
        consumer.consume();
    }
    join!(v);
}
```

Right now `join!` supports only tuples. I am looking for an alternative for that. Something similar to [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in JavaScript.

Comment: There is [tokio::task::JoinSet](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.18.2/tokio/task/struct.JoinSet.html) although it is [not yet stablized](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/4535)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also asked a similar question on the same day, but in my case I had a `Result` wrapped in a `Future`. So instead of `join_all` I had to use [try_join_all](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.try_join_all.html)

Answer (score 17):

The [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate has a [`join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) function which allows for waiting on a collection of futures:

```
use futures::future::join_all;

async fn start_consumers(&self) {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    for consumer in &self.consumers {
        v.push(consumer.consume());
    }
    join_all(v).await;
 }
```

Comment: The version of the crate where this method existed was yanked. This does not work any longer.

Answer (score 3):

`join_all`/`try_join_all` do the trick, but the output is a `Vec` that collects the results of the futures. In the modified example from above, the combined future produces a `Vec<()>`, which does not result in allocations, and even operations extending this vector should be optimized to nothing in release builds.

Even in cases when you do need the outputs, it may be worthwhile to process them as they come asynchronously in a stream, rather than wait for all of them collected. For that you can use [`FuturesOrdered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/struct.FuturesOrdered.html) or [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html), depending on whether you care about preserving the order of the original futures in the outputs yielded by the stream, or rather prefer receiving the outputs in the order of their completion. `FuturesUnordered` does not require buffering of the results and may complete faster than a `FuturesOrdered` composed of the same futures would do.

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way to do this is to use an mpsc channel where, instead of sending messages, you wait for the channel to be closed, which happens when every sender has been dropped.

See example with tokio is [here](https://tokio.rs/tokio/topics/shutdown#waiting-for-things-to-finish-shutting-down).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to `await`/`join` all your `Future`s from a normal synchronous function, and don't care about their results, you can write this:

```rust
futures::executor::block_on(async{futures::join!(future1, future2, future3, ...)});
```

You can use this macro `block_all` for more ergonomical usage:

```rust
macro_rules! block_all {
    ($($future:expr),*) => {{
        futures::executor::block_on(async{futures::join!($($future),*)})   
    }};
}
```

Usage:

```rust
block_all!(future1, future2, ...);
```