# How to tokio::join multiple tasks?

Tags: rust, async-await, concurrency, rust-tokio

Imagine that some futures are stored in a `Vec` whose length are runtime-determined, you are supposed to join these futures concurrently, what should you do?

Obviously, by the example in the document of `tokio::join`, manually specifying each length the `Vec` could be, like 1, 2, 3, ... and dealing with respectable case should work.

```
extern crate tokio;

let v = Vec::new();
v.push(future_1);

// directly or indirectly you push many futures to the vector
 
v.push(future_N);

// to join these futures concurrently one possible way is 

if v.len() == 0 {}
if v.len() == 1 { join!(v.pop()); }
if v.len() == 2 { join!(v.pop(), v.pop() ); }
// ...
```

And I also noticed that `tokio::join!` take a list as parameter in the document, when I use syntax like

```
tokio::join!(v);
```

or something like

```
tokio::join![ v ] /  tokio::join![ v[..] ] / tokio::join![ v[..][..] ]
```

it just doesn't work

And here comes the question that is there any doorway to join these futures more efficient or should I miss something against what the document says?

Comment: `tokio::join!` takes a variable number of async expressions, not a single slice / vec of async values.

Comment: misinterpreting the document of tokio I made in trying to solve this myself.   I assume that a block of async code(async function or async expression or whatever) will be treated as futures in rust. And my problem is how join these length-varied ' async expression' concurrently in a more clear way.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to wait for a list of async function calls in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326882/how-to-wait-for-a-list-of-async-function-calls-in-rust)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`futures::future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) to "merge" your collection of futures together into a single future, that resolves when all of the subfutures resolve.

Comment: thanks. Solved my problem. I didn't find the symmetrical one "join_any(...)", though. Is it somewhere else? Or absent... ?

Comment: found https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html but it cancels the other branches when the first completes...

Answer (score 33):

`join_all` and `try_join_all`, as well as more versatile `FuturesOrdered` and `FuturesUnordered` utilities from the same crate `futures`, are polled as a single combined future. This is probably fine if the constituent futures are simple and not often concurrently ready to perform work, but there are two potential problems with combining in futures this way. First, you won't be able to make use of CPU parallelism with the multi-threaded runtime. Second, this carries a [possibility of deadlocks](https://without.boats/blog/futures-unordered/) if the futures use shared synchronization primitives. If these concerns do arise, consider spawning the individual futures as separate tasks and waiting on the tasks to finish.

## Tokio 1.21.0 or later: JoinSet

With recent Tokio releases, you can use `JoinSet` to get the maximum flexibility, including the ability to abort all tasks. The tasks in the set are also aborted when `JoinSet` is dropped.

```rust
use tokio::task::JoinSet;

let mut set = JoinSet::new();

for fut in v {
    set.spawn(fut);
}

while let Some(res) = set.join_next().await {
    let out = res?;
    // ...
}
```

## Older API

Spawn tasks with `tokio::spawn` and wait on the join handles:

```rust
use futures::future;

// ...

let outputs = future::try_join_all(v.into_iter().map(tokio::spawn)).await?;
```

You can also use the `FuturesOrdered` and `FuturesUnordered` combinators to process the outputs asynchronously in a stream:

```rust
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;
use futures::prelude::*;

// ...

let mut completion_stream = v.into_iter()
    .map(tokio::spawn)
    .collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>();
while let Some(res) = completion_stream.next().await {
    // ...    
}
```

One caveat with waiting for tasks this way is that the tasks are not cancelled when the future (e.g. an async block) that has spawned the task and possibly owns the returned `JoinHandle` gets dropped. The `JoinHandle::abort` method needs to be used to explicitly cancel the task.

Answer (score 8):

A full example:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tasks = (0..5).map(|i| tokio::spawn(async move {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await; // simulate some work
        i * 2
    })).collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>();

    let result = futures::future::join_all(tasks).await;
    println!("{:?}", result); // [Ok(8), Ok(6), Ok(4), Ok(2), Ok(0)]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=953247057374f2e0060aa5e3d9f04326)